# Tornado application/json support

Tags: python, json, tornado

Does Tornado support `Content-Type "application/json"`?

According to the call stack (assuming `stream_request_body = False`), the only method called to parse the request body is parse_body_arguments (httputil.py 662), which only accepts `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and `"multipart/form-data"`

Comment: And what do you mean by *supports `application/json`*? In the request or when sending the response?

Comment: Just in the request - tornado automatically sets 'application/json' to the response

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is pretty trivial. You just have to `json.loads()` the received body and trust that it's a proper JSON-encoded dictionary (if you want, catch the exception and provide meaningful feedback). You can't expect `application/json` to be in the `Content-Type`; during a POST that'll already be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Here is a sample server:

```
import json
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        data = json.loads(self.request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        print('Got JSON data:', data)
        self.write({ 'got' : 'your data' })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tornado.web.Application([ tornado.web.url(r'/', MyHandler) ])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    print('Starting server on port 8888')
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

You can test this using e.g. `curl`:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"hello": "world"}' http://localhost:8888/
```

Comment: *during a POST that'll already be application/x-www-form-urlencoded.* That depends on the client, not on the method. It is perfectly valid to POST `application/json`; Flask's [`request.get_json()` / `request.json`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.get_json) by default only gives you JSON when the request content type has been set correctly.

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't particularly clear, but this doesn't address it. As Martijn noted, requests content type can be 'application/json'. According to the source code, the only supported type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded and clients must set that type or risk having their request body ignored. The tornado docs do say, in order to support application/json, you must override to support it, but my question was more aimed towards seeing if I had missed something in the source code and if not, the lack of support is a bug.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Agreed, my solution isn't what you're looking for; so the lack of support in the tornado server would be rather an omission. Nevertheless, I'd personally ignore the client's `Content-Type` so that you can test your code even using simple tools like `curl`...

Comment: I think I'll just patch locally and add a suggestion for enhancement. I don't think it's necessarily wise to limit incoming content type by a server (within standard content type that is). May seem petty, but would you mind removing the down vote on my question?

Comment: @Karel Will this be able to handle a json containing 400k records? or in other words what would be the best solution to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Try [tornado.escape](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/escape.html) — Escaping and string manipulation:

- Escaping/unescaping methods for HTML, JSON, URLs, and others.

```py
data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
```