# Unable to pass an image to a python server due to JSON errors

Tags: python, json, python-requests, tornado

I have a local python server running that runs json.loads(request.body)
When I pass the data to my server, I recieve `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`
This is how I am creating and passing data to my server

```
import base64
import json
import requests
sess = requests.Session()
with open("filename", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

x = {"inputs": {"key1": encoded_string}}
my_response = sess.post(<HOST>, json=json.dumps(x))
```

This is how the server handler (tornado) parses the data

```
json_data = json.loads(self.request.body)
```

Comment: Do `json=x` instead

Comment: That leads to the errors while calling json.loads() on the server side

Comment: What kinds of errors? Same one, or different?

Comment: I recieve the same error

Comment: 1) Does the `sess.post` actually send a `Content-Type` header? 2) Have you tried to decode the `request.body`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26717486/2308683

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue by adding encoded_string.decode("utf-8")